# Passing and Hiding Values from View to Controller - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to pass values from my view to controllers in codeigniter. When i pass the values to my controller, the values show in my url. How do i pass the values without showing it in the url ?

**View**

```
<p class="info"><a href="<?php echo base_url("customer/details/" . $customer->id . "/" . $customer->card . "/data"); ?>" 
class="css">Submit</a></p>
```

**Controller**

public function option_standard()

```
{
    $data['id'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data['amt'] = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $data['page_content'] = 'customer/details';
    $this->load->view(layout, $data);
}
```

Comment: Encrypt it or don't worry check this [link](https://www.amazon.in/GUTSY-Sleeves-T-Shirt-Multicolour-X-Large/dp/B07MH7Z15K/ref=bbp_bb_757550_st_Ih4H_w_2?psc=1&smid=ATMV5AS6O6TUQ) I think its fine to show data. I mean it depends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing `$customer->id` in the URL, store it as session data that is retrieved at the linked URL.

Answer (score 1):

Anything you pass without using `POST` will be visible in the query string. That's how it works. 
If you can't or won't switch to `POST` your best bet is to reduce the amount of data you pass via query string to the absolute minimum (maybe just the customer ID) and have the controller fetch out the rest. Remember, though, you still need to validate the input.

Hidden fields (which work only on forms) will also be visible in the query string if the form passes data using `GET` instead of `POST` you there's no benefit in using those in your case.

Another alternative would be to pass data back to the controller using Ajax, but the data will still be visible in the browser's console so in terms of security (or obscurity) there would be no real gain.

Comment: What if i decide to encrypt the data ? How secured is that ?

Comment: This is entirely opinion-based: my thoughts is that it's not really secure. Unless you really want to make things complicated, encrypting in the client side of things means that the client needs to have access to an encryption key, which defeats part of the purpose. Data would travel encrypted (good, but not entirely necessary if you use TLS) at the cost of the client having access to the encryption key (not good) which, unless you use a fixed key (also, not good) would also need to be posted in the clear (not good at all)